# Insert java source code into a webpage

Tags: html

I would like to insert source code into a html page.

Here you can find an [example](http://code4reference.com/2012/08/enabling-disabling-broadcast-receiver-during-runtime/).

How can I do this?

Comment: HTML and programming questions are mostly off topic for Super User, but I'm not even sure what exactly you're asking. Can't you just copy the source code into the HTML source and then apply various styles to it, e.g. monospacing, etc.? Or are you asking about the sntax highlighting specifically?

Comment: Yes I need the highlighting feature.

Comment: Should be migrated to SO. Valid question (albeit unclear one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure pure HTML can't do this by itself, and you will need to add some scripting to do the highlighting, either on the server-side or the client-side.

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is a JavaScript script that does exactly this, you add it to your HTML page by linking the required `.css` and `.js` files, and then mark your code with the required tags.